# python-oracledb timeout makes program close out

Tags: python, oracle, debugging, timeout, python-oracledb

I have a function which is supposed to retrieve the ddl as well as the indeces for a specific table from a database. Most of the time this works find, however it seems like for some specific tables I get timeouts when this function is called. To address this and avoid getting the program stuck in an infinite loop, I added a timeout for the connection and now instead of throwing an exception the program simply shuts down after the timer runs out.

So there seem to be 2 problems in play here. First, the random closing of the program when the timeout is supposed to raise an exception, and second, why the timeout happens in the first place.

Here is the code of the relevant function, which has been reduced down for simplicity:

```py
def _get_ddl(dbconnection: oracledb.Connection, table: str, schema: str):
    dbconnection.call_timeout = 2000  # 2 seconds

    try:
        # Add semicolons as terminators for this session
        cursor = dbconnection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("BEGIN\n"
                       "    DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'SQLTERMINATOR', true);\n"
                       "END;")
        # Query DDL
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', '{table}') AS DDL FROM DUAL")
        # Program breaks in the read() part here
        ddl = cursor.fetchone()[0].read()

        # Query indeces
        cursor = dbconnection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX', index_name) FROM all_indexes WHERE table_name = '{table}' AND owner = '{schema.upper()}'")
        indeces = list(str(x[0]) for x in cursor.fetchall())

        # Parses the retreived ddl and indeces into custom type
        return utils.parse_ddl(ddl, indeces)
    except BaseException:
        # ... Cut for simplicity
        raise
```

The called function runs within a tkinter application, so I am a bit irritated that the program simply stops without any notice. Also, this issue doesn't seem to occur for every table but only for some. When I execute the SQL manually I get the expected result, also when adding breakpoints and stepping through by hand I never got a timeout when querying the ddl. Only when running without breakpoints. Adding a sleep timer between the `execute()` calls also didn't help.

Does this seem familiar to anyone?
Or maybe someone has an idea on how to further debug this? Because I'm kind of out of ideas.

Comment: Use Exception rather than BaseException then add some code in the exception handler (which you have inconveniently cut) to help you understand what's happening. Python isn't just going to stop for no reason. It will only do so if there's a serious bug in some underlying code that leads to (for example) a segmentation violation, you call exit() or an exception is raised that isn't handled

Comment: I tried Exception instead of BaseException and put a breakpoint while debugging just to make sure I don't catch it somewhere by accident but it still just closes without reaching the except part.

Comment: In that case add some logging after every line of code then you'll soon find out where the problem lies. Normal development/debugging procedure

Comment: A separate issue with your code is the security risk of this kind of construct `table_name = '{table}'`.  Instead you _must_ use bind variables.  See the [doc](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html).

Comment: @ChristopherJones You are right. Since this program is not meant for public use but rather to help with some private testing this shouldn't really be an issue, but I might as well use it :)

Answer (score 1):

After a few more rounds of debugging I located the problem was happening as soon as I started working with the returned LOB object after executing DDL request. In the documentation for [Using CLOB and BLOB Data](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html#fetching-lobs-as-strings-and-bytes) I found this:

```py
# returns strings or bytes instead of a locator
oracledb.defaults.fetch_lobs = False
```

When setting this flag to false before executing the request, The timeout/crash is no longer happening for the tables which were previously crashing. I am still not sure as to why explicitly reading the CLOB data leads to timing out the database and exitting the program without any exceptions, but this seems to at least fix the issue.

Comment: Could you report it at https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/issues with the testcase so we can investigate?

Comment: Sure, when I get around to it, I will open a ticket there